# Chain rule of partial derivatives for composite functions.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

If I have a function of the form $$f(x^2+y^2)$$
How do I find the partial derivatives $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
I am not sure how $f(x^2+y^2)$ behaves. I am assuming it should of the form 
$$g(x,y)\cdot2y\quad\text{or}\quad h(x,y)\cdot2x$$

Comment: The notation $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ isn't very good, since $f$ is a function of *one* variable (which hasn't been given a name here). You should give the composite function a name, say $g(x,y)=f(x^2+y^2)$. Then $g$ is a function of two variables and you can compute the partial derivatives $\partial g/\partial x$ and $\partial g/\partial y$ in terms of the ordinary one-variable derivative $f'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(.)$ is univariate function we have$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xf'(x^2+y^2)$$similarly$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2yf'(x^2+y^2)$$therefore the differential is $$df=2xf'(x^2+y^2)dx+2yf'(x^2+y^2)dy$$therefore $$g(x,y)=h(x,y)=f'(x^2+y^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to use some different notation: 
$$f(x^2+y^2)=:f(g(x,y))=(f\circ g)(x,y) $$

Now the partial derivatives can be computed by the chain rule (in multiple dimensions): 
$$\frac{∂f}{∂x} = \frac{∂f}{∂g}\frac{∂g}{∂x} = \frac{∂f}{∂g}2x. $$
$$\frac{∂f}{∂y} = \frac{∂f}{∂g}\frac{∂g}{∂y} = \frac{∂f}{∂g}2y. $$

Since you don't know anything else about $f$, you can't simplify these terms further.

Comment: The notation $\partial f/\partial g$ is very misleading in this case, since $f$ is a function of one variable. Further, your $\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y$ should be $\partial (f \circ g)/\partial x, \partial (f \circ g)/\partial y$.